# No internet connectivity on Unidentified Network

Tags: networking

I have a Windows 7 PC. My LAN connection was running good but now it shows a Yellow mark and my internet is disconnected. tried changing cables but it does not solve the problem. I can access the router page and it is connecting to the internet. My IP setting are the same as before. In LAN settings it says unidentified network and no internet access.
i tried resetting TCP (netsh ) ,using DHCP. When I uninstall the network drivers it freezes and won't close. At first my pc says no network access on all (ie. LAN ,WIFI and USB tethering), and I was unable to access router page. But after trying so many things I am able to access the router page now.

Everytime I change adapter settings it freezes.
Please help me.

```
My IPCONFIG
Windows IP Configuration

   Host Name . . . . . . . . . . . . : I5-PC
   Primary Dns Suffix  . . . . . . . :
   Node Type . . . . . . . . . . . . : Hybrid
   IP Routing Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   WINS Proxy Enabled. . . . . . . . : No

Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection 3:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Remote NDIS based Internet Sharing Device
 #7
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 7A-BC-0F-1C-5E-F8
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::c093:1356:5b89:9a53%20(Preferred)
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.42.182(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Lease Obtained. . . . . . . . . . : 21 December 2019 20:18:57
   Lease Expires . . . . . . . . . . : 21 December 2019 21:18:56
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.42.129
   DHCP Server . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.42.129
   DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 532055444
   DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-1E-68-45-F5-9C-5C-8E-CD-51-94

   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.42.129
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled

Ethernet adapter BSNL:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Intel(R) Ethernet Connection (2) I219-V
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 9C-5C-8E-CD-51-94
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration IPv4 Address. . : 169.254.84.54(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.0.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled

Tunnel adapter Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-Interface:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-Interface
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Tunnel adapter isatap.{287FA953-BB7D-4E67-873F-00583C44C05F}:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #2
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Tunnel adapter isatap.{384A9C2D-E84D-4A69-84E3-844A1421C2ED}:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #3
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
```

Comment: You have tried many things so it may be difficult to get a starting point.  First, turn off your computer, and turn off your router. Wait one minute. Turn on the router and wait one minute. Connect the computer to a LAN port on the router and turn on the computer. Try to access the router setup page using IE and the router access URL - nominally 192.168.1.1.   Can you get the router and set it up?

Comment: i have first of all tried this but nothing .i can open router page through USB tethering while mobile connected to router wifi but if i try to open it with lan it won't open.also whenever i change ip or dns address of the adapter it freezes and the window won't even close.so i shutdown my pc to try to close but it stucks at shutting down also. i also tried to sleep my PC but it won't sleep as it was doing before so. It freezes even uninstalling or installing the network driver.i don't know what should i do. ?

Comment: Make sure UAC is ON and not turned off.  Make sure you did not enable the built in administrator Account. Then, if you have the above settings as above, you need to run the Windows 10 repair steps. (a) dism.exe  /online  /cleanup-image  /restorehealth followed by SFC /SCANNOW  .  Run both of the above from an admin command prompt.  Please let us know. Windows 10 Repair Install from the Media Creation Link is the next step

Comment: tried the restorehealh but i got error 87 .so i ran scanhealth and i got this

Comment: Checking Component Store
(f) CSI Missing Winning Component Key 0x00000000 x86_policy.8.0.microsoft.vc80.crt_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_8.0.50727.4053
(f) CSI Missing Winning Component Key 0x00000000 x86_policy.8.0.microsoft.vc80.openmp_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_8.0.50727.4053  
(f) CSI Missing Winning Component Key 0x00000000 x86_microsoft.vc80.crt_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_8.0.50727.4053
(f) CSI Missing Winning Component Key 0x00000000 x86_microsoft.vc80.openmp_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_8.0.50727.4053_none_3b0e32bdc9afe4 

Summary:
Seconds executed: 69
 Found 4 errors
  CSI Missing Winning Component Key Total count: 4

Comment: From an internet source "The DISM restorehealth error 87 may be caused by the pending Windows update. So in order to solve this error 87 DISM, you need to install all pending updates."   So make sure all Windows updates are completed and try again

Comment: also sfc does not found any violations.and the error of dism goes like this 

Error: 87
The restorehealth option is not recognized in this context.

Comment: OK i think my problem has been sorted out.i have previously comodo internet security installed.i checked by turning off the firewall completly but still i can't connect. so i uninstalled comodo but it freezes in between ,so i had to hard reboot.still i got those problems as stated before .now i tried to ran comodo setup again so it prompted that comodo is already installed .it looks like some components of the comodo firewall was blocking the access.so i downloaded the comodo uninstaller and ran it .it removed everything one key.and now my net is working again .so again thanks for the reply.

Comment: what's with comodo .i installed it again and again the problem arised .it was working good for me for years.